# Does Mathematica 8 work on Windows 8?

Tags: version-8, compatibility

I just saw that Windows 8 RTM has showed up on Technet, and I've been wondering if I should upgrade my main machine. I've been trying to determine the compatibility of various app with Windows 8 and the one thing I can't seem to find is anybody that has tried Mathematica 8 on Windows 8. Does anybody have any experience with Mathematica 8 on Windows 8?

Comment: I tried _Mathematica_ 8 on windows 8 on my new laptop and some problems occured. When sections are closed it did not recognize some equations, so I made it one by one. Also sometimes I waited hours for it to finish some calculations, but it continued running without finishing.

Comment: I don't know if anyone figured this problem out yet, but if you change the default printer from Nitro, which comes standard with Windows 8, then the Mathematica User Interface works fine. Go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers > then change the default printer from Nitro PDF Creator to Windows XPS Printer or any other printer.

Comment: My comment was deleted when @Martin's answer was converted into a comment itself. Nitro PDF does *not* come as standard with Windows 8, so this is an observation about an incompatibility with a completely different and unrelated piece of software. It's not that it shouldn't be an answer, just not an answer to *this question*. I would suggest that, particularly since Nitro PDF is not a very common program, it should ideally be made into a self-answered question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works just fine for me, and I am on windows 8. Nothing more to say really.

Screenshot:

[image]